# Get object from Task<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following method:

```
private async Task<Request> UpdateRequest(string id, RequestOutcome outcome)
{
    var request = Db.Request.Where(r => r.Id.ToString().Equals(id)).First();
    request.DateLastRead = DateTime.Now;
    request.DateConcluded = request.DateLastRead;
    request.Outcome = (int) outcome;

    Db.Entry(request).State = EntityState.Modified;

    if (await Db.SaveChangesAsync() <= 0) return null;
    return outcome == RequestOutcome.Accept ? request : null;
}
```

This is called by the following:

```
public ActionResult Accept(string id)
{
    var request = UpdateRequest(id, RequestOutcome.Accept);

    if (request.Result != null)
    {
        var c = request.DateConcluded;
    }
}
```

1. How do I check if the update was successful outside of the method?  Should I say `request != null`?  When I do, I constantly get a warning that expression is always true.
2. How do I access request.DateConcluded property because it was made into a task.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are running **asynchronous** code **synchronously**.

You must use `await` before your method to run your method asynchronously - this will handle getting the result of the task for you.

If you run the code synchronously you must then get the result of the task.

For Async:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Accept(string id)
{
    var request = await UpdateRequest(id, RequestOutcome.Accept);

    if (request!= null)
    {
        var c = request.DateConcluded;
    }
}
```

For Sync

```
public ActionResult Accept(string id)
{
    var request = UpdateRequest(id, RequestOutcome.Accept).Result;

    if (request != null)
    {
        var c = request.DateConcluded;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a little more context around your answer.  Simply posting code offers no explanation to the OP whatsoever.

Comment: I don't think `public async ActionResult Accept(string id)` will compile. Dosn't it need to be `public async Task<ActionResult> Accept(string id)`?

Comment: The ".Result" solved the issue. Thanks!